# Attempting to make FPDF flexible

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to make columns and font automatically adjust their width to the content that I feed in to it. I'd also like to position the table that I'm making on a certain part of the pdf file im making.

As you can see, I've made a function called writepdf. It works, but it doesn't tailor the table to its content. Does anyone have some tips on this?

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF
{
    // Simple table
    function BasicTable($header, $data)
    {
        // Header
        foreach($header as $col)
            $this->Cell(40,7,$col,1);
        $this->Ln();

        // Data
        foreach($data as $row)
        {
            foreach($row as $col)
                $this->Cell(40,6,$col,1);
            $this->Ln();
        }
    }

}

function writepdf($header, $data){
    $pdf = new PDF();

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->BasicTable($header,$data);
    $pdf->Output('D','recipes.pdf');
}
?>
```